# How to deal with null values when serializing arrays with protobuf-net?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

The following statement fails with `NullReferenceException`:

```
TypeModel.Create().DeepClone(new string[1]);
```

Examining the source code reveals that the exception is thrown on purpose, implying that `null` values in an array violate the protocol buffers spec (makes sense, `null` is not a repetition of any value).

OK, the spec is right, but what should we do if there is still a null value in a collection? Is there a solution, besides making sure no `null` values ever creep into our collections ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a tricky one; at the wire level, a collection is simply a repeated tag - and each element represents an object. Quite simply, there is no way of *directly* expressing a `null` in the protobuf spec.

Now, I could get dirty and have some kind of dual tag for a collection-with-nulls, but - to be honest I think it would generally be better to use a null-looking non-null object (if you see what I mean). In the case of string, *maybe* `""` would do (it depends on context, really).

I'm open to suggestions too, but... it would need to keep the limitations of the spec in mind.

Comment: It seems that the problem is with any reference type, not just the string. Or is it only the string, because it is the only core reference type?

Comment: @chibacity that does not take into account the (fixed) data format

Comment: @mark any reference type (list-of/array-of), and probably nullable-of-t (list-of/array-of)

Answer (score 8):

See this:

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=217

**Citation of the relevant part**:

> Comment 4  by project member marc.gravell, Dec 14, 2011
>
> I haven't documented that option yet (it was added as a specific request), but - *at the moment* you can only enable this via (for example):
>
> `RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof (YourType)][3].SupportNull = true;`
>
> where 3 is the field-number.
>
> This should probably be available on the attribute model too...

Note to the user "will" - the deleter of my previous answer - I know this is not the best place, but I do not know of other way to message You and being simply quiet in such case is wrong: I am sorry about the "too short" answer on the first time, BUT wouldnt the editing be more constructive approach than sudden deletion? The link I provided still DID answer the problem, as also was evidenced by the comment... I only by chance found that You did delete it.

Comment: Can we enable this in Java? Also is this available in "lite" or "full" version of library in Java?

Comment: @metsathya Unfortunately I have no Protobuf experience in Java, so cannot comment on Java options.