# ProtoBuff.Net do not support null. Why?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Why do ProtoBuff.Net not support `null`?

I was going through ProtoBuf and was wondering why `null` values are not supported. When we try to assign `null` value, it gives exception. Even ref kind like string do not support this.

```
pb::ThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull(value, "value");
```

I know that PROTOs want to keep things minimum basic so that it support large number of languages (that's why no `DateTime`), but null is a concept across languages?

Or may be I am overlooking something.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're talking about Protocol Buffers in general, or one specific implementation of them for .NET (protobuf.net perhaps?)

Comment: yes. ProtoBuf.Net to be specific.

Comment: Right - do you might want to change both your question title and the first line of the body of the question...

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331806/how-to-deal-with-null-values-when-serializing-arrays-with-protobuf-net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, because the underlying protocol specification ("protobuf") has no concept of `null` and no way of expressing it. If I can't express it in the protocol, the best that can be supported is some kind of implicit "the absence of something means leave it alone which means it will probably be `null`".

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal You might be surprised to learn that e.g. JavaScript does not really have integers :)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: afaik, Haskell uses a `Maybe` construct instead of `null`, so `null` is not entirely universal. It also looks like the use of `null` is being discouraged at Google: [Guava: using and avoiding null explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).